# Update the first view after dismissing Popover

Tags: ios, swift3

I segue from the first view controller(tableview) to the second view controller which is a tableview. After I am dont with the second view, I need to reload table view in the first controller.
popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover gets called if I tap outside the popover but what if there is another button in the second tableview which segues back to the first one?
Normally I need user to tap Add button to come out of tableview rather than tapping outside the popover. I reserve the outside tap as the cancel action.

Thank you
[image: Poppver on top of a tableview]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delegate method `popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover` does not get called when you dismiss it programmatically.

The solution is when you dismiss the popover by calling `dismiss(animated:completion:)`, you have to call the table view to reload data too.

So basically you call `tableView.reloadData()` twice. One in the `popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover`, one after `dismiss(animated:completion:)` which is in your add button tapped method.

**Update**

From you screenshot, I assume your first view controller (VC1) is the one on background, the second view controller (VC2) is the pop over.

If so, you have two options:

1. On VC2, declare a custom protocol to notify VC1 to  reload table
   view data whenever a row is selected and set delegate in VC1 to VC2.
2. Instead of using a protocol, you can simply declared a block property in VC2. For example:

   `@property (copy, nonatomic) void (^itemSelectedHandler)()`;

And when an item is selected call this (still in VC2):

```
self.itemSelectedHandler();
```

Then in VC1, after initialising VC2, which is the popover, you handle the block. For example:

```
vc2.itemSelectedHandler = ^{
    [vc1.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm not experienced with swift programming so I have to use objective c code as an example.

Comment: You don't need to convert my code if you know how to implement blocks in swift. My code is just for illustrations purpose.

Comment: No worries. Could you please accept my answer if it helps?

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3.0 version:

Popover VC:

define a property:

```
var dismissHandler: (() -> Void)!
```

call this handler when popover is being dismissed:

```
self.dismissHandler()
```

Parent VC:

pass the handler in the prepare method of the Segue

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) { 
    ...
    destinationVC.dismissHandler = {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    ...
}
```